# how to pass array in data (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i Pass array to ajax request can any one suggest me how can i fetch array in my my php file .
**JavaScript**

```
var value1 = [];  
$.each($('.form-control_1'), function() {
    var total_stock;
    var total_stock = this.id;
    //console.log(total_stock);
    value1.push(document.getElementById(total_stock).value)
    console.log(value1);
});

console.log('starting ajax');

$.ajax({
    url: "insert_inventory.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { value1: value1 },
    success: function (data) {
        var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(dataParsed);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give me any code or tutorial reference.

Comment: how can i make value1 an array and assign value @jeroen

Comment: var value1 = [];  AND value1.push(document.getElementById(total_stock).value)

Comment: Thanks @Roy can you please tell me how can i fetch this array in insert_inventory.php

Comment: $data = $_POST['value1']; foreach($data as $value){ echo $value}

Comment: Thanks for your help @Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `array` like this:

```
var value1 = []; //Outside loop.
value1.push(document.getElementById(total_stock).value) //Inside loop.
```

And you have to fetch data in `PHP` like this way:

```
$data = $_POST['value1']; 
foreach($data as $value){ 
   echo $value;
}
```

Hope it helps.